# Count entris from table in H2 Database Engine

Tags: java, sql, database, h2

I know that I can count the entries in SQL with

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM table
```

but I don't know how do perfom that in Java.

This is my Code to perform a SQL command.

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM table")
```

Result:

```
rs2: org.h2.result.LocalResult@41cf3f60 columns: 1 rows: 1 pos: -1
```

But it should return > 20

My code:

```
Connection conn = null;
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:h2:" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/sorter/database", "", "");
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

Toast.makeText(context,
                    String.valueOf(stmt.executeQuery(sql)),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

conn.close();
    if (conn != null)
        conn.close();
```

Comment: Please show us the code where you retrieve the count from the `ResultSet`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see is the `toString()` method of the `ResultSet` you never actually retrieve a value from the result.

`executeQuery` returns a `ResultSet` that you use to get the actual data. It is *not* the result of the query directly (think about how this should work when returning multiple rows and multiple columns)

You need to do something like this:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
int count = -1;
if (rs.next())
{
  count = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

This is all nicely explained in the JDBC Tutorial: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/resultset.html#998035

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is

```
ResultSet rs=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table").executeQuery();
if(rs.next()) sysout(rs.getInt(1));
```